# PHPMailer - SMTP ERROR - Can't get the email

Tags: php, phpmailer

Here is my PHPMailer code to send SMTP email:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {  
    //Recipients
    $mailerErrors = [];
    $mail->Debugoutput = function ($str, $level) use (&$mailerErrors) {
        $mailerErrors[] = [ 'str' => $str, 'level' => $level ];
    };

    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                      
    $mail->isSMTP();                                          
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';                             
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                 
    $mail->Username   = 'mygmail@gmail.com';                      
    $mail->Password   = 'my-gmail-pass';                   
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;           
    $mail->Port       = 587;         

    $mail->setFrom("support@shibbir.dev", "shibbir");
    $mail->addAddress($email, $name);  //Add a recipient

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);//Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = $email_subject;
    $mail->Body = "<p>$email_body</p>";
    $mail->AddEmbeddedImage($url,'greetingcard','greetingcard.'.$extension);
    $mail->Body .= '<img src="cid:greetingcard">';
    $mail->send();

    echo "<div class='alert alert-success mt-5'>Successfully sent your message.";
    
} catch (Exception $e) {
    
    //echo "<div class='alert alert-danger mt-5'>Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
    
    echo '<pre>';
    
    if (count($mailerErrors) > 0) {
        echo "Captured debugoutput: \n - " . join("\n - ", array_map(function ($errInfo) {
            return "[{$errInfo['level']}] \"{$errInfo['str']}\"";
        }, $mailerErrors)) . "\n";
    } else {
        echo "Send returned truthy.\n";
    }
}
```

But I got this error message:

> - [1] "SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server:  (0)"
> - [2] "SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host."

I search on this site and google but can't fix the issues.

Comment: It's quite obvious that your script cannot connect to Gmail's SMTP server. Check the network connection & firewall settings.

Comment: why it's cannot connect to the SMTP server? Can you tell me?

Comment: there are a million reasons. You have to figure it out. Ask your network admin.

Comment: @Raptor not a good answer but will try it.

Comment: `https://mxtoolbox.com/` try this for checking domain/connection SMTP problems

Comment: @Siddharth let me check it.

Comment: @Siddharth do you mean to check this: smtp.gmail.com?

Comment: No, enter your domain there like `yourdomain.com` then look up if `DNS Record Published` is green checkmark then there is no problem with your server

Comment: Fet more details about SMTP select `Test Email Server` for  from the dropdown and submit you will got report

Comment: @Siddharth I got this: https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=mx%3awww.shibbir.dev&run=toolpage

Comment: Are you testing the script from your home or from your server on your hosting provider? Did you check if your hosting provider blocks TCP port 587 ?

Comment: @IVOGELOV I am testing it from the localhost as well as from server too.

Comment: Try setting the SMTPDebug to SMTP::DEBUG_CONNECTION and then post the complete log when testing from your local PC.

Comment: I got this: https://codeshare.io/BAlVwd

Comment: `Too many bad auth attempts` - sounds like you made too many unsuccessful attempts already, so Google has blocked you now, at least for a while. Sending emails via Google's servers isn't straight forward any more, just supplying credentials is not enough - you would need the "allow less secure apps" option enabled in the Google account. But that will reset itself regularly (at least for accounts that do not use 2FA, I think?), so it would be better to use XOAUTH2 to begin with - https://phppot.com/php/sending-email-using-phpmailer-with-gmail-xoauth2/

Answer (score 2):

I have also faced the same issue. I just found a less secure app function that got disabled by google and it's no longer accessable.

You have two ways to send emails using PHPmailer now.

1. Using the XOauth method by Google. (It's a little bit tricky method)
2. Using App password (the simple and easy way)

to generate an app password you need to enable 2 step verification in your Google account. Then below the 2-step verification, you will see the App password link to generate the app password.

See this link for more info about app passwords. https://support.google.com/mail/answer/185833?hl=en

But I hope this is a temporary solution until Google blocks it.

For a permanent solution, you need to use the XOauth method.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have generated the app password but how can I use it in the PHPMailer?

Comment: Just like old method, use the generated app password as email password in your PHPMailer.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Google Less Secure Apps warning!]

Clearly we cant use google to send mail only using username and password.

Answer: Enable 2FA in Google Security Settings and create an App Password for this specific mailer. Use that app password as a gmail password.

This works for now. Until Google decides other way!

Comment: How to crate App Code, I have enabled the 2FA.

Comment: https://myaccount.google.com/security under security settings, there is "Signing in to Google" which includes App Passwords